# Regex to do not match certain sequence

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file as below:

```
1.1 - Hello
1.2 - world!
2.1 - Some
data
here and it contains some 32 digits so i cannot use \D+
2.2 - Etc..
```

so i want a regex to get 4 matches in this case for each point. My regex doesn't work as I wish. Please, advice:

```
private readonly Regex _reactionRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*-\s*(.+)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

even this regex isn't very helpful:

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*-\s*(.+)(?<!\d+\.\d+)
```

Comment: you need to show what you expect to capture

Comment: Your 3th match must be `"2.1 - Some
data
here and it contains some 32 digits so i cannot use \D+
"`?

Comment: FYI I changed the answer and [online demo](https://ideone.com/MGgxQK) so that it shows you not just how to get the text part of the string: `Hello`, but also the digits if you want: `1.1 - Hello`. So you now have both options. Take a look at the bottom of the demo, it shows the output of the code.

Comment: @nPn i wanted a capture that starts with `\d+\.\d+` and match everything until next `\d+\.\d+`. I got an answer, and it is i'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, this regex will do it:

```
(?sm)^\d+\.\d+\s*-\s*((?:.(?!^\d+\.\d+))*)
```

This is assuming that you want to capture the point, without the numbers, for instance: just `Hello`

If you want to also capture the digits, for instance `1.1 - Hello`, you can use the same regex and display the entire match, not just Group 1. The online demo below will show you both.

**How does it work?**

1. The idea is to capture the text you want to Group 1 using `(parentheses)`.
2. We match in multi-line mode `m` to allow the anchor `^` to work on each line.
3. We match in dotall mode `s` to allow the dot to eat up strings on multiple lines
4. We use a negative lookahead `(?!` to stop eating characters when what follows is the beginning of the line with your digit marker

Here is full working code and an [online demo](https://ideone.com/MGgxQK).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program {

static void Main() {
string yourstring = @"1.1 - Hello
1.2 - world!
2.1 - Some
data
here and it contains some 32 digits so i cannot use \D+
2.2 - Etc..";
var resultList = new StringCollection();
try {
    var yourRegex = new Regex(@"(?sm)^\d+\.\d+\s*-\s*((?:.(?!^\d+\.\d+))*)");
    Match matchResult = yourRegex.Match(yourstring);
    while (matchResult.Success) {
        resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Whole Match: " + matchResult.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Group 1: " + matchResult.Groups[1].Value + "\n");
        matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}

Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for! And explanation is really really helpful! :)

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky It was a pleasure, glad to hear it worked for you! If you want to see more simple regex tricks, you might enjoy [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204), I had a lot of fun with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This may do](http://regex101.com/r/mE4tJ8) for what you're looking for, though there is some ambiguity of the expected result.

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*-\s*(.+?)(\n)(?>\d|$)
```

The ambiguity is for example what would you expect to match if data looked like:

```
1.1 - Hello
1.2 - world!
2.1 - Some
data here and it contains some 
32 digits so i cannot use \D+
2.2 - Etc..
```

Not clear if `32` here starts a new record or not.